# Cygwin Folders Deleted

Tags: windows-8, cygwin

This is very weird.

Under Windows 8, I have a computer running bash script calling Cygwin routines downloading files and executing Windows programs over them.

After using *Cygwin* almost everyday, today at 16:45 UTC (last modification date), the `sbin\`, `bin\` folders under the `Cygwin64\` folders appear empty.

Other Cygwin folders also appeared to be changed today at that same time, `etc\`, `lib\`, `Packages\`, `tmp\`, `usr\`, `dev\`. They have folders inside, but no folder have any files on it (i.e. empty). 
Of course, `var\log\` is empty too.

I don't have any specific clue about how to debug this. No other user access this computer (?).

My only suspect is some other service being updated -e.g. Windows Defender- and deleting the Cygwin folders by considering them a "virus", or something like that. But nothing appear under `History>Quarantined Items`, `History>Allowed Items` or `History>All Detected Items`.

Other possible interaction is with some insubordinate `choco` auto-update (?). Which I really doubt, because `choco` never does auto-updates.

A last theory is some insuburdinate bash code deleting the `cygdrive\` folder unintentionally (how?) (why?).

I don't have any other possible cause.

Where should I start looking for realizing what happened and eventually fixing this?

Comment: Are you logged in with the right user? Was there a Windows update? Have you tried reinstalling over the top of your previous installation?